Python: how to run the equivalent of the entry_point `foo.bar:baz` during development?
I have in my setup.py:
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            # Error at runtime: module planning_web does not exists 
            'foobaz = foo.bar:baz',
        ],
    },


so that when I install it, it creates automatically a script foobaz that runs the function baz from the file foo/bar.py, and it works great (tested with nix). But this is quite annoying to develop a program this way as I constanly need to build my package for any tiny change, while usually flask can automatically reload itself when the code changes.
So is there a command like:
python -X foo.bar:baz

in order to run automatically what the entry script would run once installed? I realized I could do python -m foo.bar to run the foo/bar.py file (doing python foo/bar.py directly would produce an error about ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package), but I can't find how to run a specific function inside.

This question is similar to: Run function from the command line. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Olivier this work indeed, thanks. If there is no simpler solution than manually importing and executing a code I guess yes this can be seen as duplicate I guess. I was hoping to see a more specialized solution I guess.
